# actionscript 3 sleep?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a simple actionscript function

```
var string:String = "TEXT REMOVED";
var myArray:Array = string.split("");
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);

function frameLooper(event:Event):void {
    if(myArray.length > 0) {
        text1.appendText(myArray.shift());
    }else{
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
    }
}
```

And I want to have it sleep after calling the framelooper so it is a little bit slower. How could I do this?

btw, I'm fairly new and found this code on a tutorial, it's a text typing effect, if there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Sleep statements don't make much sense in an asynchronous event-based language. There are however some pseudo-threading libraries for as3, but I doubt that's what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Timer:

```
var string:String = "TEXT REMOVED";
var myArray:Array = string.split("");
var timer : Timer = new Timer (1000, myArray.length);
timer.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, frameLooper);
timer.start();

function frameLooper(event:Event):void {
    text1.appendText(myArray.shift());
}
```

This will execute the frameLooper on every second for exactly as many times as the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is better than the timer method, just an option

```
var string:String = "TEXT REMOVED";
var myArray:Array = string.split("");
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);

const WAIT_TIME:int = 10;
var i:int = 0;
function frameLooper(event:Event):void {
    if(myArray.length > 0) {
        if(i==0){ 
            trace(myArray.shift()); 
            i = WAIT_TIME;
        };
    } else {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
    }
    i--;
}
```